# Is there a way to launch emacs merge without first opening emacs and using M-x and more?

Tags: emacs

I sometimes want to merge multiple pairs of files, suppose I want to merge fileA.old and fileA.new, as well as fileB.old and fileB.new..and so on.Currently I have to open emacs. Do `M-x ediff-merge-files` and enter name of first file, return key, name of second file, return key..and im in merge mode...is there a way to launch emacs with both file names as arguments and land in merge mode?

Comment: Do you mean `ediff-merge-files`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass Lisp code to Emacs through the command line:

```
emacs --eval '(ediff-merge-files "path/to/file1" "path/to/file2")'
```

Of course this could be wrapped in a script to make it more convenient to call. For instance, in a bourne shell, you could do a simple version like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# check correct invocation
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
   echo "USAGE: $(basename "${0}") <file1> <file2>"
   exit 1
fi

# check that file1 exists and is readable
if [ -f "${1}" ]; then
    if [ ! -r "${1}" ]; then
        echo "Cannot open '${1}', access denied."
        exit 3
    fi
else
    echo "File not found: '${1}'"
    exit 2
fi

# check that file2 exists and is readable
if [ -f "${2}" ]; then
    if [ ! -r "${2}" ]; then
        echo "Cannot open '${2}', access denied."
        exit 5
    fi
else
    echo "File not found: '${2}'"
    exit 4
fi

# invoke emacs
emacs --eval "(ediff-merge-files \"${1}\" \"${2}\")"
```

If you save this in a file `ediff` on your `$PATH`, you can then simply write:

```
ediff file1 file2
```

on the command line and Emacs will pop up with the two given files in `ediff-mode`.

Comment: Awesome, this makes it handy to launch eshell with --eval (eshell) and maybe even gdb i need to try that thanks!

Comment: For eshell, also try `-nw` to run emacs inside the terminal window instead of opening a new window.